# exception in android

Tags: android

I am using gesture detector using swipe action in webview and using activity group manager I am getting the below exception

```
11-29 20:01:04.418: ERROR/ActivityThread(4236): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
11-29 20:01:04.438: WARN/Checkin(4236): Can't update stat BROWSER_SNAP_CENTER: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
```

can anybody tell what is the problem?

Comment: You will have to provide some more info, but the problem is not in the swipe :)